# I have created model form using django. The form isnt saving on submit though. The page keeps displaying the invalid form page

Tags: python, html, django

`index.html`

```
 <div class="container add_dog_form">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row" id="namefield">
                    {{ form.as_table }}
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <button type="Submit" id="form_submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

`forms.py`

```
class DogForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Dog
        fields = ['name', 'dog_pic']
```

`views.py`

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "takyi1/index.html"
    context_object_name = "dogs_context"
    dog_form = DogForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.dogs_context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.dogs_context['dogs'] = self.dog
        self.dogs_context['form'] = self.dog_form
        return self.dogs_context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.dog_form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('Valid Form')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('inValid Form')
```

Comment: Why are you using `ListView`? You should use` CreateView` instead.

Comment: You forgot to include `action` in form tag

Comment: @bichanna ive changed to CreateView. It didnt work though. Ive realised the problem is with the Image. when i use only the name field in the form, it saves successfully. BUt when i add the imagefield, thats when it keeps returning invalid form. Any help with that please?

Answer (score 0):

easiest method is to building a html form and saving data into Model by post method.

Using of ModelForm just makes it difficult.

If you use below code, It works perfectly

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "takyi1/index.html"
    model = Dog
  
    def post(self, request):
        self.model(name=request.POST['name'],
                   dog_pic=request.POST['dog_pic']).save( )
        return HttpResponse('Valid Form')
```

Comment: i keep getting a multidictvalue error

Comment: It actually works now

Comment: form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)

Comment: `request.FILES` was missing. You got that